# How to access 2D array using single for loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a 2D array which has 10 rows and 10 columns and I want to access a column's element from each row like this:

```
myArray[0][9]
myArray[1][4]
myArray[2][5]
myArray[3][9]
myArray[4][5]
myArray[5][9]
myArray[6][8]
myArray[7][9]
myArray[8][7];  
myArray[9][8]
```

The code that I have used:

```
for(var i=0; i<theatregoers.length; i++)
    {
       myArray[i][9].position=true;
      
       
    }
```

Note: I do not have any idea how to change column numbers like this each time when loop run. I do not want to use the nest loop, just using a single loop.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @tdranv thanks for ur response, actually I want to access column of each arrow according to the pattern that I mentioned above.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the pattern?

Comment: @Jerome myArray[0][9]
myArray[1][4]
myArray[2][5]
myArray[3][9]
myArray[4][5]
myArray[5][9]
myArray[6][8]
myArray[7][9]
myArray[8][7]
myArray[9][8]

Comment: is there a particular pattern you want in calling the column number or it could be just random?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this. put the column indexes/number in an array like:

```
  let colArray = [9,4,5,9,5,9,8,9,7,8] 
    
  for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){  
        myArray[i][colArray[i]].position=true;              
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop your array like this

```
var row = 10;
var column = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < row * column; i++) {
     myArray[Math.floor(i / row)][i % column].position = true;
}
```

Comment: The OP asked for an arbitrary pattern for the second index, so this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Avius: agree, OP added more info later in the comment